# DOM4J Element.attributes().containsAll() returns unexpected value

Tags: java, dom4j

I am using DOM4J to do analysis of two XML elements.  The elements are the following:

```
<element1 attr="val">text</element1> //org.dom4j.Element = e1
```

and

```
<element1 attr="val">OtherText</element1>  //org.dom4j.Element = e2
```

Both of these elements are stored in `org.dom4j.Element` instances, `e1` and `e2`.

I expect that both of these elements have the same attributes, so I expect that:

```
e1.attributes().containsAll(e2.attributes())
```

returns `true`, but it actually returns `false`.

When I inspect both of these attributes, I find the following string representations:

```
org.dom4j.tree.DefaultAttribute@552c8fa8 [Attribute: name attr value "val"]
```

and

```
org.dom4j.tree.DefaultAttribute@26d58939 [Attribute: name attr value "val"]
```

Am I missing something obvious?  Beyond writing my own `containsAll` function to inspect this behavior, can you think of anything else I should try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll have to write your own `containsAll()`.  You're seeing the default `List.containsAll()`, which compares items using `equals()`.  Since [DefaultAttribute doesn't override](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/dom4j/tree/DefaultAttribute.java.html) `equals()` to make your comparison evaluate to `true`, you're out of luck.